# What is a “submission”?

Tags: legal-terms, rules-of-court, definition

It was used in a recent answer to mean “a legal argument”. Is it necessarily of this nature? Or is it broader (i.e. “anything one submits”)?

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=submission

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Submission* is a legal term of art in Commonwealth jurisdictions, which refers specifically to OED sense 2(b):

> Something submitted for decision or consideration; a point of view, a theory of a case; a proposal, an application; *spec*. **a proposition or argument submitted by counsel to a judge or jury**.

Parties can *submit,* in the ordinary sense of the word, various documents for the court's consideration, including evidence. *Submissions,* however, are legal arguments, not evidence. Preparing submissions is part of advocacy and in jurisdictions with a split legal profession, specialised in by barristers.

This is the sense in which [Supreme Court of the United Kingdom Practice Direction 3](https://www.supremecourt.uk/docs/practice-direction-03.pdf) uses the word, to describe the written submissions to be filed in advance, and the oral submissions to be made at any hearing, as distinct from the various other documents a party must file to conduct a Supreme Court appeal.

Answer (score 2):

It's broader, and means anything that is put to the court to consider.

See these examples of it's use in the [Criminal Procedure Rules 2020](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2020/759/contents):

> [Rule 3.9](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2020/759/rule/3.9?timeline=false) the submission of proposed questions

> [Rule 13.7](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2020/759/rule/13.7?timeline=false) written material that was submitted to the court

> [Rule 45.6](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2020/759/rule/45.6?timeline=false) Where the application was under paragraph (4)(d), the Crown Court officer may—
>
> - (a)submit it to the Crown Court; or
> - (b)serve it on the magistrates’ court officer, for submission to the magistrates’ court.